# Difference between JprogressBar.setValue(0) and JProgressBar.SetValue(10)

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

Hi any one help me on this.

I am new to Swing based applications. Actually in my application using `IVisualExecutionContext` interface to show the long-drawn processes and 
I've created 2 to 3 `IVisualExecutionContext` objects and resetting on top of
previous one. In reset method if I put `JProgressBar.setValue(0)` progress bar
getting struck and if I make that 0 to 10 it never strucks. Let me know what is
the difference between `JProgressBar.setValue(0)` and `JProgressBar.setValue(10).`

```
sample code :

    IVisualExecutionContext veCtxt = view.getVisualExecutionContext();
    if (veCtxt != null) {
        veCtxt.reset();
        veCtxt.setMessage(" ");
    }
```

Comment: What is this IVisualExecutionContext interface?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: An interface between domain processes and the application user interface to display the status/progress of long-drawn processes. Also provides a mechanism to cancel long domain processes based on user interruptions.

Comment: The effect depends on the `BoundedRangeModel` of your `JProgressBar`. See [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) regarding "long-drawn processes."